# Point manipulations to list form

Tags: list-manipulation, data, coordinate-transformation

I tend to do a lot of code the manual way, which doesn't work out for bigger data sets. I wanted to know if there were in built functions to do the following;

```
data = {{300, .024}, {400, .035}, {500, 0.046}, {600, 0.058}, {700, 
0.071}, {800, .084}, {900, .097}, {1000, .111}, {1100, .126}, \
{1200, .14}, {1300, .155}, {1400, .17}, {1500, .186}, {1600, .202}, \
{1700, .219}, {1800, .235}, {1900, .252}, {2000, .269}};

A = {{300^2, 400^2, 500^2, 600^2, 700^2, 800^2, 900^2, 1000^2, 1100^2,
1200^2, 1300^2, 1400^2, 1500^2, 1600^2, 1700^2, 1800^2, 1900^2, 
 2000^2}, {300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 
1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};

B = {.024, .035, .046, .058, .071, .084, .097, .111, .126, .14, .155, \
.17, .186, .202, .219, .235, .252, .269};
```

So for A, given the data points, how can I get mathematica to output this exact list without having to manually write them in. A is essentially a list of the x coordinates squared followed by just the x coordinates and then a list of "1's" that match the number of data points. And for B how do I set a variable equal to just the x coordinate of a set of points.

Comment: Note that `B` is simply `data[[All, 2]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A={data[[All, 1]]^2, data[[All, 1]], Table[1, Length@ddata]};
B=data[[All, 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a1 = data[[All, 1]]^# & /@ {2, 1, 0} ;

a2 = Table[data[[All, 1]]^(3 - i), {i, 3}]

a1 ==  a2 == A
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

```
A = Transpose[Table[x^{2, 1, 0}, {x, First /@ data}]]; B = Last /@ data;
```